# Finitely presentable objects in functor categories

Tags: ct.category-theory

Given a locally finitely presentable category $\mathcal{C}$ it is well-known that every functor  category $[\mathcal{A},\mathcal{C}]$ (where $\mathcal{A}$ is a small category) is also locally finitely presentable. Is there a concrete description of the finitely presentable objects in such categories?

If this is not possible in general, what about special cases like $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{Set}_{fin}^{op}$?

Comment: Coequalizers of finite coproducts of representables.

Comment: @FernandoMuro What representables? $\mathcal{C}$ is not $\mathbf{Set}$.

Comment: Well, your conditions ensure that C is equivalent to [B, Set] for B the category of finitely presentables in C, so you end up with [AxB, Set]

Comment: Sorry, preserving finite limits in B.

Answer (score 6):

When $\mathcal{A}$ is a finite category, the finitely presentable objects in $[\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{C}]$ are precisely the diagrams that are componentwise finitely presentable: see e.g. Proposition 2.23 [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.5227.pdf). The general case is harder to describe. There are two steps:

1. First, determine the finitely presentable objects in $[\operatorname{ob} \mathcal{A}, \mathcal{C}]$; these will contain e.g. "finitely supported" families of finitely presentable objects.
2. Then, determine the left adjoint of the restriction functor $[\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{C}] \to [\operatorname{ob} \mathcal{A}, \mathcal{C}]$; by general nonsense, the restriction functor is finitely accessible and monadic, and the finitely presentable objects of $[\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{C}]$ will be the objects in the smallest full subcategory that is closed under finite colimits and that contains the free "algebras" generated by the finitely presentable objects in $[\operatorname{ob} \mathcal{A}, \mathcal{C}]$.